# Responsive CSS: Replicating how Facebook's chat panel disappears below a certain browser window width

Tags: facebook, css, responsive-design

Notice how facebook's right hand, ~200px-wide, chat panel/column disappears when you shrink your window below a certain width. (It then switches to a pull-out menu at the bottom)

I presume this is some sort of responsive CSS - can anyone offer any guidance on how I can achieve a similar effect with a similar right-hand panel on my own site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's using [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

```
<style>
@media (min-width: 701px) {
  //css for wide screen
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  //css for narrow screen
}
</style>
```

Comment: To anyone else looking to do this, the solution to get the main window to resize depending on whether the chat column is hidden is to use position absolute and right:0 or right:200px depending on the above